# HTML Upload file hangs for +3M file, is it host issue?

Tags: php, html, apache, upload, hosting

I have the most annoying problem, boils down to this simplest HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="/testupload.php">
  <input type="file" name="thefile">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

when selecting a small file, all is good.
When selecting a 3M file (example for big file), the process simply hangs. No error, no breaks, no nothing. If I use firebug I see the file being submitted is 0 size.

I am thinking this is something on the Apache side, but my precious host (InMotion VPS) gives me the "GoDaddy" response "it's in the code" so they can't take care of it, albeit the "code" is 4 lines of the most basic HTML.

I do see an error in my logs "Handler for (null) returned invalid result code 70007", googling it I get possoble mod.security issues or restarting httpd, which I did to no avail.

It used to work when I was developing that piece of application, and uploaded files like crazy for couple of days. Then it stopped.

Any takers?

Comment: did you go through this - http://serverfault.com/questions/231331/handler-for-null-returned-invalid-result-code-70007-causing-error-500

Comment: Take a look in php.ini, especially upload_max_filesize and post_max_size.

Comment: sagar - yes I did. This error is probably result of nothing going on, so it throws an erro of "nothing happening". This is what this error means.
Borachio - I check phpinfo() and my limits and well above the 3M. Furthermore, I could upload yesterday and today I can't, so what gives?....